# How to check client certificate revocation during validation process with local CRL file (C#)

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-core, certificate, certificate-revocation

I am trying to validate a client certificate using `HttpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback`. I have built my `x509chain` with my `ChainPolicy` parameters.

I have locally my CRL (.pem) file and i would like to add it to the revocation process.

I was thinking of doing something like [CRL validation](http://blog.ginzburgconsulting.com/real-time-crl-validation-for-x-509-certificates-in-net/), importing into my `X509Certificate` an `X509Extension` with a distributionPoint oid but i have trouble understanding it.

Here is a piece of my callback code

```
private static Func<HttpRequestMessage, X509Certificate2, X509Chain, SslPolicyErrors, bool>
    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback()
{
    return (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
    {
        X509Certificate2 ca = new X509Certificate2(@"pathToCa\\ca.crt");

        X509Chain chai = new X509Chain();
        chai.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(ca);
        chai.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.ExcludeRoot;
        chai.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online;
        chai.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.AllFlags;
        chai.ChainPolicy.VerificationTime = DateTime.Now;
        try
        {
            if (!chai.Build(cert))
            {
                return false;
            }
            foreach (X509ChainStatus status in chai.ChainStatus)
            {
                if (status.Status == X509ChainStatusFlags.UntrustedRoot) continue;
                if (status.Status == X509ChainStatusFlags.OfflineRevocation) continue;
                if (status.Status == X509ChainStatusFlags.RevocationStatusUnknown) continue;
                return false;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }

        return true;
    };
}
```

Thank for your help & clarification

Comment: whats the question?

Comment: @Mike_G Sorry it's my first post. How can I add my local CRL file in the revocation process?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to host your own CRL, you will need server set up somewhere, so it can host your crl just like an html page.

So, for example, if you using openSSL or preferably **LibreSSL** to create your own certs, in your config file, you will add the following:

```
crlDistributionPoints  = URI:http://myserver.com/mycert.crl
nsCaRevocationUrl =  http://myserver.com/mycert.crl
```

(You could try using absolute paths to the keys above, but I am not sure that would work, if it does let me know)

There are several tutorials to help  get this set up, https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/ is pretty good and detailed.

While doing this myself, I found that when you call build chain, the .Net framework checks the chain, so you should not need to add and extra code to insure that it checks the CRL as this happens automatically. (You can check that the crl is being fetched by checking your server log files)

You can test this by adding your own cert to your CRL, and you should find that you get

```
X509ChainStatusFlags.Revoked
```

Hope that helps

Comment: All right, your solution works well but my question is about offline revocation from a local file..

Comment: did you try change the path for nsCaRevocationUrl /crlDistributionPoints to something like \\Machinename\c$\certrevlist\my.crl

Comment: I have found that dotnet check only crls with http source: [dotnet cource](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/bffef76f6af208e2042a2f27bc081ee908bb390b/src/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates/src/Internal/Cryptography/Pal.Unix/CrlCache.cs#L255)

Comment: Thanks, that is good to know. I guess it is not possible, unless you install a "local" webserver.

Answer (score -1):

I have requirement to validate the certificate against the CRL. before using it to further process.
i extracted the CRLDP url of the certificate and download the .crl file . now i have to read the revocation list of the .crl file and validate the serial number
of certificate in the  revocation list of downloaded crl.

```
public static void getCRL()
{
    string strLocalPath = "C:\\EnjoyCoding"+ "\\.crl";

    var certificate_List = CertificateService.FindCertificateInStores("Alstom Solutions Root CA - PREPROD");

    if (certificate_List.Count > 0)
    {
        crlDP_URL = X509Certificate2Extensions.GetCrlDistributionPoints(certificate_List[0]);
    }
    using (System.Net.WebClient Client = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        Client.DownloadFile(
                // Param1 = Link of file
                new System.Uri(crlDP_URL[0]),
                // Param2 = Path to save
               strLocalPath
            );
    }
}
```